# Magento: can diffrent magento websites installations use same Database?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I intially had an instance of magento installed that was using a databse, then i intalled another intance of Magento Using the same database, but the problem that occured is that now my old website is getting redirected to new website.

I had **configured** my old Website's url from **localhost** to **somethingElse**.

**So, is there a method such that both the websites use the same Database. If so then how to configure it to do so?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install another Magento in order to create a new Website, Magento already supports multiple websites on the same instance. 
Here is a detailed explanation on Magento websites,stores and store views: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work/

Comment: Hi, i actually made changes to the core files and some problem occured, so wanted to make fresh install to test my new code, but i also want my to retain my old website. and dont take me wrong, i am a beginner and i now know that i shouldn't have done that.

Comment: Hi, try to specify a table_prefix when install Magento so all the tables will have the new prefix, this way your new installation will not collide with the old one.